# Multiple aliases for a namespace?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to have a namespace that has all the declarations of more than one other namespace? Like this:

```
namespace std {...};
namespace glm {...};

namespace mynamespace = std; //mynamespace is an alias for std
namespace mynamespace += glm; //mynamespace will hold glm functions as well.
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Sure

```
namespace mynamespace
{
   using namespace std;
   using namespace glm;
}
```

Comment: support for correct braces ;D! +1

Answer (score 53):

You can use `using` to achieve this:

```
namespace mynamespace {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace glm;
}
```

Comment: Omg, there is a braces-war going on here! Voting for your answer :-P

Comment: Obviously voting for the braces that don't look totally disgusting.

Comment: I feel that the original one with a semicolon was more beautiful, expressing a sense of symmetry with classes and structs, perhaps as to say that aggregating these identifiers all serve a similar vein of grouping things together under one umbrella -- a world united through braces ending in a semicolon. The only finishing touch necessary would be a semicolon at the end of each function. Ignore the compiler warnings -- the compiler doesn't understand *art*.

Comment: Downvoted for ugly braces